# Calling a C++ function from C# program

Tags: c#, c++, point-cloud-library

I run into an issue calling a c++ function from a c# program. It works fine until I add the line "`pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII("test_pcd.pcd", cloud);`". Then I get the error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in MIxed_Mode_Calling_App.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in MIxed_Mode_Calling_App.exe
Unable to load DLL 'C:\Users\d\Box\Daniel\RE\Surface Project\PCL_Project\MixedMode\build\Debug\MixedMode.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

The location is correct and the MixedMode.dll can be found at that location.

Why is the above named line causing issues in the dll but works fine in a simple .cpp program?

Thanks!

c++ function "MixedMode.h":

```
#ifndef MIXED_MODE_MULTIPLY_HPP
#define MIXED_MODE_MULTIPLY_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

extern "C"
{

    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall mixed_mode_multiply(int a, int b) {
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;

        // Fill in the cloud data
        cloud.width = 5;
        cloud.height = 1;
        cloud.is_dense = false;
        cloud.points.resize(cloud.width * cloud.height);

        for (auto& point : cloud)
        {
            point.x = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
            point.y = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
            point.z = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        }

        pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII("test_pcd.pcd", cloud); //If this line is removed it works.
        std::cerr << "Saved " << cloud.size() << " data points to test_pcd.pcd." << std::endl;

        for (const auto& point : cloud)
            std::cerr << "    " << point.x << " " << point.y << " " << point.z << std::endl;

        return (0);
    }
}
#endif
```

C++ "MixedMode.cpp":

```
#include "MixedMode.h"
```

c# program "Program.cs":

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Mixed_Mode_Calling_App
{
    public class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"C:\Users\d\Box\Daniel\RE\Surface Project\PCL_Project\MixedMode\build\Debug\MixedMode.dll", EntryPoint =
        "mixed_mode_multiply", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int Multiply(int x, int y);
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int result = Multiply(7, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}", result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

As part of the troubleshooting, I created this .cpp program which runs fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

int
main()
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;

    // Fill in the cloud data
    cloud.width = 5;
    cloud.height = 1;
    cloud.is_dense = false;
    cloud.points.resize(cloud.width * cloud.height);

    for (auto& point : cloud)
    {
        point.x = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        point.y = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        point.z = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    }

    pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII("test_pcd.pcd", cloud);
    std::cerr << "Saved " << cloud.size() << " data points to test_pcd.pcd." << std::endl;

    for (const auto& point : cloud)
        std::cerr << "    " << point.x << " " << point.y << " " << point.z << std::endl;

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: The error message is misleading; it's not saying MixedMode.dll is missing, it's saying it can't _load_ MixedMode.dll because _some_ module can't be found. Probably a dependency of MixedMode.dll is missing. Adding that line of code might be adding another dependency that you haven't copied in.

Comment: Since its a dependency of the .dll it has to be added to .h file with include correct? If so should an error show that up when I build the .dll? Or do I have to add the dependency in the .cs file? 
When convert my .h file to an executable .cpp file (change the extern "C" ... to int main()) and use the same includes it runs fine. So I think I should have all the necessary includes.